# Why my Android studio projects are unable to sync?

Tags: android-studio

My android studio projects are unable to sync.

Studio is throwing error which is:

**Error thrown after initial sync failure**

```
Gradle sync failed: Received invalid response from the daemon: 'org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.ForwardInput@1085bbb' is a result of a type we don't have a strategy to handle. Earlier, 'Build{id=eeb34e7d-7321-46b4-8841-4d3cd2eec1ef.1, currentDir=E:\AndroidStudioProjects\Doors}' request was sent to the daemon. Diagnostics:
       No diagnostics available.
       Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

If i create a new project then its working fine.

Link for log file: [log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b0pb2wiawu5u3zi/idea.log?dl=0)

Im on win 10(32-bit) and using android studio 2.2.2.

It started happening after my machine encountered sudden shut down while i was working on one of my android project.

Comment: have you tried: `tools` -> `Android` -> `Sync project with Grade Files`

Comment: yup,but no luck

Comment: Have you also tried `Build` -> `Clean Project` followed by `Rebuild Project`

Comment: Yes, all of them. But no luck.Seems like a bug where studio is failing to read some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the reason for the issue but you can try this to hopefully fix it

`File -> Invalidate caches / Restart...`

Remove the `.gradle` folder from the home directory

Restart Android Studio and let it download and sync, if not syncing you can try `Tools` -> `Android` -> `Sync Android with Project Files`